# Why won't this typedef work if my class is templated?

Tags: c++, typedef

The following nested typedef works:

```
struct FOOO
{

    struct TRAITS
    {
        using size_type = std::uint32_t;
    };
    void func(TRAITS::size_type arg) { } // This works fine if FOOO is not a template class.
};
```

However, if I make FOOO a template class, it doesn't work:

```
template <typename T>
struct FOOO
{

    struct TRAITS
    {
        using size_type = std::uint32_t;
    };
    void func(TRAITS::size_type arg) { } // This works fine if FOOO is not a template class.
};

    //syntax error: identifier 'size_type'
```

I'm wondering why this is, I can't make sense of it.  I am on Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Inside a template, you end up with a dependent name, so you need `void func(typename TRAITS::size_type arg)`.

Comment: @cigien Damnation! I always fall for this!!!